# Make spark-sql UDF available in Scala spark data frame DSL API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, geomesa

How can I access geomesas UDF in spark scala dataframe (not textual) api? I.e. how to convert

How can I make sql UDFs available in the textual spark-sql API available in the scala data frame DSL?
I.e. how to enable instead of this expression

```
spark.sql("select st_asText(st_bufferPoint(geom,10)) from chicago where case_number = 1")
```

something similar to

```
df.select(st_asText(st_bufferPoint('geom, 10))).filter('case_number === 1)
```

How to register geomesas UDF in a way that these are not only available to the sql text mode. `SQLTypes.init(spark.sqlContext)` from https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/f13d251f4d8ad68f4339b871a3283e43c39ad428/geomesa-spark/geomesa-spark-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLTypes.scala#L59-L66 only seems to register textual expressions.

I am already importing

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

so these functions

https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/828822dabccb6062118e36c58df8c3a7fa79b75b/geomesa-spark/geomesa-spark-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLSpatialFunctions.scala#L31-L41

should be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `callUDF` function from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("callUDF")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.createDataset(List("abcde", "bcdef", "cdefg")).toDF("str")
df.createTempView("view")

spark.sql("select length(substring(str, 2, 3)) from view").show()
df.select(callUDF("length", callUDF("substring", $"str", lit(2), lit(3)))).show()

spark.stop()
```

Tested with Spark 2.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `udf` function in the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` you're importing e.g.

```
val  myUdf = udf((x: String) => doSomethingWithX(x))
```

you can then use myUdf in the DSL as in df.select(myUdf($"field"))

Comment: But SQLTypes.init(spark.sqlContext) is already registering the functions. So could this be a problem to use your solution?

Comment: yes it does but you lose the refrece ie. if the line is  val ST_DistanceSpheroid: (Geometry, Geometry) => jl.Double =
    nullableUDF((s, e) => fastDistance(s.getCoordinate, e.getCoordinate)). you need to use ST_DistanceSpheroid in the DSL